# How to add a new product type on woocommerce product types?

Tags: customization, templates, plugins, hooks

I want to add a new custom "product type" to woocommerce plugin:

[image]

Tried to duplicate one of currently exist product type files [(woocommerce template structure)](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) as a new file (file name and inside commented name) but not worked!

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The add to cart template is only 1 of the many things you'll need to do. Each product type has it's own class in the `/includes/` folder. Each one extends the `WC_Product` class.

To add items to the list you've screencapped (which is on the admin side and not the front-end, unlike the `add-to-cart.php` template, you will need to filter `product_type_selector`.

```
add_filter( 'product_type_selector', 'wpa_120215_add_product_type' );
function wpa_120215_add_product_type( $types ){
    $types[ 'your_type' ] = __( 'Your Product Type' );
    return $types;
}
```

then you'll need to declare your product class. The standard naming system is `WC_Product_Type_Class` so in this example it would be:

```
class WC_Product_Your_Type extends WC_Product{
    /**
     * __construct function.
     *
     * @access public
     * @param mixed $product
     */
    public function __construct( $product ) {
        $this->product_type = 'your_type'; // Deprecated as of WC3.0 see get_type() method
        parent::__construct( $product );
    }

     /**
     * Get internal type.
     * Needed for WooCommerce 3.0 Compatibility
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_type() {
        return 'your_type';
    }
}
```

You are asking a very complicated question and I can't provide a more complete answer. Hopefully this sets you on the right path.  I highly encourage you to read the code in WooCommerce. It is very well commented and you can see how they are handling the different product types.

**Edit** Added WC3.0 compatibility to product type class.

Comment: For people from ✨ the future ✨ finding this, here's a blog post that might provide some helpful additional information: http://jeroensormani.com/adding-a-custom-woocommerce-product-type/

Comment: Love that! But for people of the future, the `$this->product_type` will not be accurate for WC2.7+.

Comment: @helgatheviking Any points as to where to find more up to date info in particular about the product_type? I keep bumping into those "old" tutorials using only that syntax.

Comment: @kontur you will need to add a `get_type()` method to your class. It should return the product type. ex: `public function get_type() { return 'your_type'; }` See my edit.